# I think, I think, I think

Tags: riddle

I think,

I think,

I think that,

Someone needs to tell me why we're here and what to do while I'm here.

When we finally shuffle off of this mortal coil,

I would like to know what will happen.

and

I think I can, I think I can, I think I can.

and

Coincidences are also funny things...

and

I think that existential questions satisfy the thoughts of man,

And that this might just- coincidentally-

become a very existential riddle.

and

This is the last "and"

Numbers are very funny things, when they keep recurring...

Like a dozen, or

Half of a dozen (Which appears three times, in fact)

(Try to guess what this poem/riddle is describing. I'm sorry if it's a bit vague, I might have to go back and edit later.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess :

> " The Devil's Thoughts "
>  by Samuel Taylor Coleridge

Few Comments :

> Half A Dozen = 6, repeated 3 times to get 666 = Number of the Devil
>  Couple that with "think" and "Poem" to get the answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the answer is:

> A train of thought. The poem/riddle represents a stream of consciousness, and the line "I think I can" repeated references a train from *The Train that Could*

Comment: Good answer, but not exactly what I was going for. It does cover most of the riddle's components, but not all. I'm sorry if it's too vague... It's my second riddle.

Comment: @Quark Did you mean the Stream of Consciousness???

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> **Contemplating Death / Mortality and Existence?**
>
> "When we have shuffled off this mortal coil" is a line from a *soliloquy* in William Shakespeare's play Hamlet.
>
> It seems like that is exactly the same poetic device you're using, letting the character ponder and think, with the reader witnessing all the thoughts.

Comment: A very good answer that is basically like Prem's answer, just interpreted differently. I tried to use the Shakespeare to indicate a work of literature. Good job!